# MVC Razor Pages hosting Angular 4 app

Tags: c#, angular, razor, asp.net-core-2.0

I am hosting an Angular app in a MVC core 2 site. I'm using Razor Pages.

i.e. localhost:4000/MyRazorPage

When I navigate to the Razor Page that hosts the app the app loads and behaves properly including handling routing within the app.

i.e. localhost:4000/MyRazorPage/home
i.e. localhost:4000/MyRazorPage/document/1

What I'm having trouble with is deep linking into the app

i.e. localhost:4000/MyRazorPage/document/1 typed directly into the address bar of my browser

I expected that this in the Startup would make it work but it doesn't seem to. It may be that I'm using the wrong action because Razor Pages work a little differently to MVC

`routes.MapSpaFallbackRoute(
    name: "MyRazorPage-fallback",
    defaults: new { area = "", controller = "MyRazorPage", action = "Index" });`

Help appreciated

Comment: I faced this when I removed SpaFallbackRoute from startup.cs

Comment: I still have the MapSpaFallbackRoute in my startup

Comment: Your MapRoute  controller = "home" ?

Comment: @k11k2 Are you saying that if the host page was called MyHostPage.cshtml then the controller would be home and the action would be MyHostPage?

Comment: @Peter Have you found any solution to this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up adding this code to my startup.cs file

```
  public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            app.UseBrowserLink();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
        }

        app.UseStaticFiles();

        app.MapWhen(context => context.Request.Path.Value.StartsWith("/Reader"), builder =>
        {
            builder.UseMvc(routes =>
            {
                routes.MapSpaFallbackRoute("reader-fallback", new { area = "Reader", controller = "Default", action="Index" });
            });
        });


        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "areaRoute",
                template: "{area:exists}/{controller=Default}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });
    }
```

The app.MapWhen function says when the route has "Reader" in it change the spa fallback. You would do this for each app.

I host each app in its own Area in the site